# How to use Entity Framework BulkInsert in Asp.net Zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-boilerplate

I am using ASP.NET Zero to insert large amounts of data from Excel into the database and it is slow. So I thought of using Entity Framework Extensions for BulkInsert but don't really know how to use it.. I get an error

> The type arguments for the method DbContextBulkExtensions.BulkInsert can not be inferred from usage

This is my code.. Any help please?

```
private readonly IRepository<InventoryBalance> _repository;
   
public void Create(InventoryBalance input)
{
    _repository.GetDbContext().BulkInsert(input);
}
```

Comment: Am using https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions and not https://entityframework-extensions.net..However i have tried changing it to but same errors.           public void Create(IEnumerable<InventoryBalance> inputs)
{
    _repository.GetDbContext().BulkInsert(inputs);
}

Answer (score 0):

The BulkInsert method takes an `IEnumerable<T>` parameter. Try changing your code to something like this and pass it a collection of inputs instead of just one.

```
public void Create(IEnumerable<InventoryBalance> inputs)
{
    _repository.GetDbContext().BulkInsert(inputs);
}
```

Also note that you will need to set up the context factory somewhere. Try adding this line to your repository's constructor.

```
EntityFrameworkManager.ContextFactory = context => context;
```

https://entityframework-extensions.net/context-factory